# Split multiple text files in a Directory java

Tags: java, file, split

I am trying to split text files in a directory along a line 'END OF CUSTOMER STATEMENT' and I store the result files into a temporary directory. The split happens only for the first file while the other file is ignored, what is the problem with my code. I was expecting the for loop will engulf all the files in the directory? Here is my code.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
public class SplitFiles {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File f = new File("D:/statements/");
        String[] filenames = f.list();
        File[] texts = f.listFiles();
        String lines = "";
        for (int m = 0; m < filenames.length; m++) {
            try {
                 int count = 0;
                FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("D:/statements/" + filenames[m]);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:/DFCU Statements/statement" + count + ".RPT");
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));

                while ((lines = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    String mine = lines.trim();

                    if (mine.startsWith("END OF CUSTOMER STATEMENT")) {
                        bw.close();
                        count++;
                        fos = new FileOutputStream("D:/DFCU Statements/statement" + count + ".RPT");
                        bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (mine.isEmpty()) {
                        continue;
                    } else {
                        bw.write(lines);
                        bw.newLine();
                        bw.flush();
                    }
                }
                fos.close();
                fs.close();
                br.close();
                bw.close();
            } catch (Exception ag) {
                System.out.println(ag);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you change the input path to : D:/statements/*.* ? What happens then ? Are you sure you are reading all the files ? Can you print all the file names and see if every one of them is getting read ? Last but not least do your file names contain any unusual characters ?

Comment: @Stanley- for what purpose you are using that 'count' variable?

Comment: @FathahRehmanP I am using it to Name the result after spliting as Statement1 statent2 and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should do this in the first place (there are possibly more bugs)

```
int count = 0;
for (int m = 0; m < filenames.length; m++) {
   ...
```

**UPDATE** besides, remove your count++ and place it after each file creation

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:/DFCU Statements/statement" + count + ".RPT");
count++;
```

then it will work as expected

Comment: I assume the OP intended for a counter per file he split - therefore resetting the counter within the loop is the correct option here.

Comment: It seems Stanley overwrites the old files due to resetting the counter

Answer (score 3):

I assume that since the target files have nothing that distinguishes them from each other (they are all named `statementX.RPT`) - that the last file is actually the one you have in your output - but this is only a guess.

try to change your output file to be named `"statement." + m + "." + count ".RPT"` and that way you will have unique output files.

Also, take note to the following comments:

1. When using the `File` class, the `listFiles` API is more usefull (in my opinion) - from each file you get you can query `getName` and `getPath`.
2. About this line: `FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("D:/statements/" + filenames[m]);` - if you used the results you got from `listFiles` you could replace it with `FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(files[m]);` - no need to hard-code the path.

Comment: +1 each input file is being split into output files which overwrite any previous ones.

Answer (score 1):

You should modify your code. Otherwise instead of creating two output files your code will create three output files. Here is the correct code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
public class SplitFiles {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File f = new File("D:/statements/");
        String[] filenames = f.list();
        File[] texts = f.listFiles();
        String lines = "";
         int count = 0;
        for (int m = 0; m < filenames.length; m++) {
            try {

                FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("D:/statements/" + filenames[m]);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));

                FileOutputStream fos = null;
                BufferedWriter bw = null;

                while ((lines = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    String mine = lines.trim();

                    if (mine.startsWith("END OF CUSTOMER STATEMENT")) {
                        if(bw!=null)
                        {
                        bw.close();
                        }
                        count++;

                        continue;
                    }
                    if (mine.isEmpty()) {
                        continue;
                    } else {
                        if(bw==null)
                        {
                             fos = new FileOutputStream("D:/DFCU Statements/statement" + count + ".RPT");
                             bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
                        }
                        bw.write(lines);
                        bw.newLine();
                        bw.flush();
                    }
                }
                fos.close();
                fs.close();
                br.close();
                bw.close();
            } catch (Exception ag) {
                System.out.println(ag);
            }
        }
    }
}
```